# Will reference in NHibernate result in more memory consumption

Tags: c#, nhibernate, memory, relationship

I'm trying to learn Fluent-NHibernate with tutorial I found on its site: https://github.com/jagregory/fluent-nhibernate/wiki/Getting-started

In this code you can see reference to Store object:

```
public class Employee
{
   public virtual int Id { get; private set; }
   public virtual string FirstName { get; set; }
   public virtual string LastName { get; set; }
   public virtual Store Store { get; set; }//<-- here
}

public class Store
{
  public virtual int Id { get; private set; }
  public virtual string Name { get; set; }
  public virtual IList<Product> Products { get; set; }
  public virtual IList<Employee> Staff { get; set; }
}
```

Lets say I will have 10000 of Employees(or more) and each will have reference to store instance. What will happen if we have only one store and many references to it. Will each element store only reference to memory of store object, or will all of them store individual object resulting in huge memory taken away ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on how you're using ISession. Inside single ISession you'll get only one instance of `Store`. Different ISessions will have different instances of `Store`.

Comment: So with using only one ISession using whole object, or just it id(integer) is basically the same in regards to memory usage?

Comment: With one ISession you'll have only one `Store` object with specific id. So 10000 `Employee` will reference the same `Store` object inside that ISession.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. There will be only one instance with reference from every Employee instance.